# Using Java selenium, I want to select excel sheet rows [sA1 to B4] and paste it in browser

Tags: excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using Java selenium, I want to select excel sheet rows [say A1 to B4] and paste it in browser

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvRkb.jpg)

How can select excel data copy it and paste in browser at once using java selenium
what I do manually is I actually select all rows and columns from A1 to B4 using mouse and and hit [ctrl +c] then navigate to browser and hit [ctrl + v] so whatever Excel data we have is shown in browser. Same process I want to carry out using automation

Answer (score 0):

As much as I can understand with the above question. I think the approach you're taking to the problem can be improved. `Selenium` is mainly a browser automation library, it can help you with all the action that you can do with a browser. It's present on their website itself.

```
Selenium automates browsers. That's it!
What you do with that power is entirely up to you.
```

What you are looking for requires other libraries that can support your case. You can use the `Apache POI` java  library which can read the content from an excel file. Read the rows and columns using that library and then send them to the browser using selenium.

There is a really great article by @angiejones where she has explained how to read data from excel files. Sharing it for refere

https://angiejones.tech/using-apache-poi-to-read-excel-files/

https://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Thanks Techrookie89 for prompt response.I tried thoose excel sheet operations methods of reading the data and using it automation. However requirement I have is quite tricky, what I do manually is I actually select all rows and columns from A1 to B4 using mouse and and hit [ctrl +c] then navigate to browser and hit [ctrl + v] so whatever Excel data we have is shown in browser. Same process I want to carry out using automation.

Comment: @ssnssn in that case you can go with the Robot class present in the java library. It allows you to simulate clicks and keyboard events of the operating systems.